# Pointer hover animation for a five-star-rating picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I want to shorten my code. You can see the following code i used many function for addClass, removeClass. But it is not usefully. Can do my work in one hover function ? If yes can anyone help me ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.star-one').hover(function() {
       $('.star-one').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       var therate = $(this).attr('id');
       for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.star-one-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       };
    });
    // Red
    $('.star-two').hover(function() {
       $('.star-two').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       var therate = $(this).attr('id');
       for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.star-two-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       };
    });
    // Pink
    $('.star-tree').hover(function() {
       $('.star-tree').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       var therate = $(this).attr('id');
       for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.star-tree-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       };
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GvStarContainer">
  <!--Style 1 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex1-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-one-1 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-one-2 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-one-3 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-one-4 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-one-5 rate-btn star-one"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 1 FINISHED-->
  <!--Style 2 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex2-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-two-1 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-two-2 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-two-3 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-two-4 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-two-5 rate-btn star-two"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 2 FINISHED-->
</div>
```

This is my Demo page: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKorea)**

I was thinking of [simplifying the code like this](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/XjvMBg), but then the CSS animation wouldn't work.

> ```
>  $(".star").hover(
>     function() {
>       var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
>       prevStars.toggleClass('rate-btn-hover');
>     }
>   );
>
>   $("body").on("click", ".star", function() {
>     $(this).siblings().removeClass('rate-btn-active');
>     var prevStars = $(this).prevAll().addBack();
>     prevStars.addClass('rate-btn-active');
>   });
> ```

This is shorten code [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKorea).

This is old code [demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/XjvMBg).

You can see old code demo not have any css animation problem.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what your exact problem is. Are you saying you want to put all 3 JS function in one function?

Comment: @Mast Thank you for your insterest Dear. I have tried it you can see my answer below. What i want exactly. Thanks you so much again.